# Why is my complete table in bold?

Tags: html, css

Good day,

I have the following table in html which is entirely displayed in bold. What I don't understand is that I have set the property font-weight to normal in my train_timetable_table element:

Have I missed to add a new element to my CSS configuration which would **only** show the first row in bold (identified in my example below by * I would like this row in bold *)

I hope that my question is clear enough and hopefully will save some time for future searches.

Many thanks for your time and your help to solve this matters.

Best wishes

```css
 /* Page entière (utilisé pour avoir une couverture globale en couleur) */
        body {
         background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/
         background-color:#ccffcc;  /*day mode*/
        }
        
        /* Affichage de l'en-tête */
        #header {
         font-family:Arial;
         text-align:center;
         position: relative;
         background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/     
         background-color:#ccffcc;  /*day mode*/
         color:black;
         padding-top: 5px;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-bottom: 0px;
         padding-left: 0px;
         width:1000px;
         height:80px;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de la barre de navigation */
        #nav {
         font-family:Arial;
         position: relative;
         line-height:50px;
         background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/
         background-color:#ccffcc;  /*day mode*/
         height:434px;
         width:60px;
         float:left;
         padding-top: 5px;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-bottom: 0px;
         padding-left: 0px;
        }
        
        /* Affichage des données essentielles (section) */
        #section { 
         font-family:Arial;  
         font-size: 100%;
         float:left;
         background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/
         background-color:#ccffcc;  /*day mode*/
         padding-top: 5px;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-bottom: 0px;
         padding-left: 10px;
         height:434px;
         width:870px;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de la barre de pied d'écran (version de domooaweb) */
        #footer {
         font-family:Arial;
         font-size: 60%;
         text-align:center;
         background-color:#005580;  /*night mode*/
         background-color:#ccffcc;  /*day mode*/
         color:black;
         clear:both;
         padding-top: 0px;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-bottom: 0px;
         padding-left: 0px;
         height:12px;
         width:1000px;
        }
        
        #validity {
         font-family:Arial;
         font-size: 100%;
         color:black;
         position:fixed;
         top: 110px;
         left: 640px;
         width:350px;
        }
        
        #reserved {
         position:fixed;
         top: 250px;
         left: 200px;
         color:black;
         font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:18px;
        }
        
        #home_automation_tab
        {
         position: fixed;
         height: 350px;
         width: 900px;
         top: 140px;
         left: 140px;
        }
        
        #train_station img {
         position: fixed;
         top: 160px;
         left: 140px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
        
        #weather_img img {
         position: fixed;
         top: 160px;
         left: 140px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
        
        #emergency_img img {
         position: fixed;
         top: 160px;
         left: 140px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
        
        /* Affichage du logo */
        #logo img {
         position: fixed;
         top: 12px;
         left: 5px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de l'icône météo */
        #meteo_icon img{
         position: fixed;
         top: 12px;
         left: 935px;
         z-index: 2;
        }  
     
        /* Affichage des prévisions météorologiques (températures) */
        .meteoforecast_temperature{
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 26px;
         font-weight: 900;
         color: black;
        }
        
        /* Affichage des prévisions météorologiques (jour) */
        .meteoforecast_day{
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 22px;
         color: black;
        }
        
        /* Affichage des prévisions météorologiques (condition) */
        .meteoforecast_condition {
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 18px;
         color: black;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de la météo dans le monde (scroller) */
        #worldwide_meteo {
         font-family:Arial;
         font-size: 18px;
         color:black;
         top: 150px;
         left: 145px;
         width: 800px;
         position: fixed;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de l'image d'erreur 404 (page non trouvée) */
        #err404  img{
         position: fixed;
         top: 180px;
         left: 180px;
        }
        
        /* Affichage de l'image de la météo mondiale */
        #ww_meteo img{
         position: fixed;
         top: 200px;
         left: 165px;
        }
        
        /* Affichage des icônes météo mondiale */
        Marquee img {
         vertical-align:middle
        }
        
        /* Table pour horaires de train (lundi-samedi) */
        #table_train_timetable1
        {
         position: fixed;
         top: 290px;
         left: 139px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
              
        /* Table pour prévisions météo 3 jours */
        #table_forecast_3days
        {
         position: fixed;
         top: 290px;
         left: 139px;
         z-index: 2;
        }
         
        .train_timetable_table
        {
         border: 1px solid black;
         color: black;
         border-color:gray;
            font-weight:normal;
        }
        
        .train_timetable_table td
        {
         font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:14px;
         padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         overflow:hidden;
         word-break:normal;
         border-color:gray;
         font-weight:normal;
        }
        
        .train_timetable_table th
        {
         font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:14px;
         font-weight:normal;
         padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         overflow:hidden;
         word-break:normal;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .train_timetable_table .title
        {
         font-weight:bold;
         color:black;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .train_timetable_table .tablerows
        {
         vertical-align:top;
         font-weight:normal;
        }
        
        .weather_forecast_table
        {
         border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .useful_numbers_table
        {
         border: 1px solid black;
         color:black;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .temps_parcours_table
        {
         border: 1px solid black;
         color: black;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .temps_parcours_table td
        {
         font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:14px;
         padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         overflow:hidden;
         word-break:normal;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .temps_parcours_table th
        {
         font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size:14px;
         font-weight:normal;
         padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         overflow:hidden;
         word-break:normal;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        .temps_parcours_table .title
        {
         font-weight:bold;
         color:black;
         border-color:gray;
        }
        
        h2
        {
         position: fixed;
         top: 100px;
         left: 140px;
         color:black;
        }
        
        progress[value] {
          /* Reset the default appearance */
           -moz-appearance: none;
           appearance: none;
        
           /* leave defaults in for other browsers */
           background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
           color:purple; 
        }
        
        progress::-webkit-progress-bar { 
         /* ici les styles généraux pour Webkit */
         background-color: purple;
        }
        
        progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
          background-color: purple;
        }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Domuob | home</title>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="360">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_day.css" />
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id="header">
              <h1></h1>
            <div id="section">
              <h2>Horaires de train</h2>
              <div id="train_station">
                <img src="assets/pictures/zoo.png" alt="" style="width:850px;height:97px;">
              </div>
              <div id="table_train_timetable1">
                <table class="train_timetable_table" style="width:840px">
                  <colgroup>
                    <col style="width: 210px">
                    <col style="width: 210px">
                    <col style="width: 210px">
                    <col style="width: 210px">
                  </colgroup>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="title" colspan="4"><img src="assets/icons/logo_s.png" alt =""  style="width:15px;height:15px;">** I would like this row in bold **</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>05:36 &nbsp; 05:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>06:06 &nbsp; 06:21&#9830; &nbsp; 06:36 &nbsp; 06:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>07:06 &nbsp; 07:21&#9830; &nbsp; 07:36 &nbsp; 07:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>08:06 &nbsp; 08:21&#9830; &nbsp; 08:36 &nbsp; 08:51&#9830;</b></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>09:06 &nbsp; 09:21&#9830; &nbsp; 09:36 &nbsp; 09:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>10:06 &nbsp; 10:21&#9830; &nbsp; 10:36 &nbsp; 10:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>11:06 &nbsp; 11:21&#9830; &nbsp; 11:36 &nbsp; 11:51&#9830;</b></td>
                    <td class="tablerows"><b>12:06 &nbsp; 12:21&#9830; &nbsp; 12:36 &nbsp; 12:51&#9830;</b></td>
                  </tr>
          </table>
              </div>
              <div id="validity">
                <p align="right">Horaires valables du 11.12.2016 au 09.12.2017</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">      Duobweb version 0.0.7    </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: you do realize, the `<b>` in `<b>05:36 &nbsp; 05:51&#9830;</b>` stands for bold ???

Comment: Please see my comment to Harden. And not necessary to write in such an agressive way. I apologised for the mistake, hoping that you never do mistakes!

Comment: seen bud, calm down. happens with us all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `<b>` tag everywhere in your table that's why it’s showing bold everywhere. Try to change that with `<span>` or something else.

Comment: Oh. I feel really sorry. I missed the <b> tag. Many thanks and again sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

because, by default `b` tag have `font-weight: bold` property.

Insert this code,if want remove affect `font-weight`:

```
.train_timetable_table .tablerows b {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have added **`<b>`** **Bold** tag around the contents of Each cell, it is overriding the CSS property you set in the CSS File:

```
.train_timetable_table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    border-color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Remove the **<strike><b></strike>** tag around each cell values.

Comment: Always **Welcomed** @Laurent